# Background image of a column goes to end of screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a WordPress block I've made and I'm trying to get the image (background image) to break the container and extend beyond to the end of the screen. How can I achieve this?

[image]

```css
.container {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: auto auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.col {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.border {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
}

.btn {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.body {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col border" style="background: url('https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1694825173871-7b5df4d57ba5?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2310&q=80') no-repeat center/ cover; min-height: 460px;">
    </div>
    <div class='col'>
      <h2 class='copyimage__title'>My Title</h2>
      <div class=" body">This is the copy</div>
      <div class="align-items-center">
        <a href=" #" class="btn btn-primary">
                  Button
                </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You won't get the bg image to extend beyond its container like that. Better to start with a full-width container.

Comment: @ralph.m let's say I do start with a full-width container, how would I got about lining up the content with the rest of the page thats in regular width containers.

Comment: FYI, it's a really bad idea to override essential library classes like that. You should never touch containers, rows, columns or other core features. You make life much more difficult for yourself and other developers down the road doing that. Work _with_ the library, not against it, and use custom classes for your overrides if you really need them.

Comment: @isherwood yes, I know this - I am just using this as the example to quickly mock up what I currently have.

Comment: I don't see how that changes things. You're using those elements in ways they aren't intended to be used, and there are classes to do much of it. Seems like you should just be using [Bootstrap's flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a negative `margin` to `.border`. But for this you need to know the width of the `.container`.

I see you set `.container { max-width: 80%; }`. It doesn't work now because bootstrap styles are added later. But for an example solution to your problem, we'll add `!important` and assume the width of the container is `80vw`.
Then we set `.border { margin-right: calc((100vw - 80vw) / -2) }`

P.S. You will have to now also install `body{ overflow-x:hidden; }` because `vw` don't take scrollbar into account. In bootstrap, by the way, the width of the container is fixed. You can put it in a css variable and use it in a similar way. It's a wonder they haven't done it yet...

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  --container-width: 80vw;
  max-width: var(--container-width)!important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.col {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.border {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: calc((100vw - var(--container-width)) / -2); /*  */
}

.body {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col border" style="background: url(https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1694825173871-7b5df4d57ba5?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2310&q=80) no-repeat center/ cover; min-height: 460px;"></div>
    <div class="col">
      <h2 class="copyimage__title">My Title</h2>
      <div class="body">This is the copy</div>
      <div class="align-items-center">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will put the background image outside the container.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: auto auto;
}

.border {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  max-width: 280px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.btn {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.body {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <h2 class='copyimage__title'>My Title</h2>
      <div class=" body">This is the copy</div>
      <div class="align-items-center">
        <a href=" #" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="border" style="background: url('https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1694825173871-7b5df4d57ba5?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2310&q=80') no-repeat center/ cover;">
</div>
```